# What is the encryption used here?

Tags: encryption, decryption

This is the string:
UVRWUVRsUXRNRGRSUlZBdE9FTllUbGM9

I want to decode it, but I'm not sure what decoder to use.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you can  try  CyperChef

https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/

you can easily try different N-bases decryption  & others